# Dúvida de como tratar o evento de Button

Tags: android

Olá! Sou novo em programação e Android e me deparei com uma dúvida.

O que vejo na maioria dos tutoriais é assim.

1. Cria-se um botão.
2. Declara esse botão como atributo da classe.
3. Recupera a referência dele atravéz do id dentro de onCreate.
4. Aplica um listener neste botão e faz a implementação.

Só que outro dia vi algo diferente.

1. Cria-se um botão.
2. Cria-se um método public recebendo um objeto View como parâmetro.
3. No atributo onClick do xml faz esse botão apontar para este método e implementa-o.

O fato de eu não declarar nem recuperar a referência pode me gerar algum problema?

obrigado

Comment: o unico problema que poderia ter seria o fato de precisar desse mesmo botão em outro ponto da tela, mas disparando um outro evento.

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener

Comment: obrigado a todos, vou ler o link